# How can I repair Windows 10 boot on SSD after formatting old HDD

Tags: windows-10, boot

I used to use a HDD with Windows 10, and then bought a SSD. Using Windows 10 on the first HDD, I performed an installation of Windows 10 on the SSD. But I only wanted to use the Windows installation on the SSD. I tried to format the first HDD using the Windows installation on the SSD but the system would not allow that for some reason.

After that, I had used a tool through boot and forced formatting the HDD and its partitions. I thought that the Windows OS on the SSD would work properly, but then it stopped working and even the startup repair doesn't show up on Windows. I've tried everything.

It seems that had boot data on the HDD was lost when it was formatted.

I want my PC to recognize the Windows installation on the SSD. If I do this, maybe the Windows installer can repair the boot.

Comment: How you repair a Windows 10 boot, depends, whats wrong with it.  You have not provided enough details to determine that.

Comment: This happened after format HD and his partitions. What other kind of details I can provide?

Comment: Its not clear which installation your trying to solve.  The one on the HDD or the one that doesn't exist on the SSD.  You also said, "Until I had the brilliant idea of using a tool", which doesn't tell us very much.

Comment: I'm trying to solve SSD Windows installation that may be corrupted after I formated HD and his partitions.

Comment: If you formatted the boot partition on the HDD, then you will have to place the boot partition, on the SSD instead.  If you don't know how to that manually, i suggest you started the entire process over, and just format the SSD then have the Windows installer do it for you.  You can't recover the boot partition, since you got rid of it, so your looking at very complicated steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used bootrec command to restore my windows boot info.

Using windows CD/DVD installation  command prompt:

```
> bootrec.exe
> bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

rebuildbcd search for windows installtions not included in the boot configuration data.

After this my windows installation is able to be repaired by windows repair tool of CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to detail different procedures for doing this depending on if you have a UEFI system, or a BIOS system, or if you have a UEFI system that uses BIOS to boot, but ultimately the best thing for you to do is this:

If you don't have any important files on your SSD, and you have your product key, start over from scratch, just get a Windows 10 disc (If you need to get the iso and burn your own, you can here [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/)) make sure only your SSD and your disc drive are plugged in and boot to the disc, wipe the drive and install from scratch. If you boot to the disc from UEFI, it will install in a UEFI boot manner. If you boot to it from BIOS, it will install in a BIOS manner.

If you do have important files on your SSD, then you want to get them off before doing anything else. Even if you wanted to try and fix it manually, having important files on a drive you're trying to fix boot problems with is a bad idea, and once they're off, you're better off starting from scratch. Windows is always more stable from scratch.

I'm not saying you can't do this manually. You definitely can. It would involve making an EFI partition on your SSD and pointing it properly to Windows for UEFI, or repairing the Master Boot Record and pointing it to Windows, and you can do that booting from a Windows install disc and learning how to use bcdboot, bcdedit, booting from a partition management disc (like gparted) to move partitions around and make room for the EFI partition and things like that, but starting from scratch will be easier and faster, and I think most experts here will agree with me on that.

Comment: what about the user license that was lost on the HD?